# how to post and save the changes after sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I trying to sort the list of titles of the pages I can see the correct order after sorting in firebug console when i am hitting sort button it is not taking my request to the requested method. here is my jquery code I am kinda new in it.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         $("#sortable").sortable();
         $sortable = $("#sortable");
         $( "#sortable_nav_items" ).sortable({
             placeholder:"sortable-placeholder",
            update: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log($("#sortable_nav_items").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"}));
            }
        });
        var order = $("#sortable_nav_items").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"});
            console.log(order);
        $sortable.bind('sortupdate',function(event,ui){
            console.log($(this).sortable('toArray'));
            $.post(
                "content.cfc",
                {method:"sortOrder",data:$(this).sortable('toArray')}
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my list.

```
<cfoutput>
    <div class="well"> 
        <ul id="sortable_nav_items" class="list-group">
            <cfloop query="_q">
                <li class="list-group-item" pageid="#_q.id#" navOrder="#_q.nav_order#">
                    #_q.title#
                </li>
            </cfloop>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></i>
                Sort
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

can anyone please help me out what i have to do in it to post the changes to the requested method ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not bound click event for your button.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var order = $("#sortable_nav_items").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"});
   $.post(
     "content.cfc",
     {method:"sortOrder",data:order}
   );
});
```

Here is jsfiddle (no coldfusion stuff though): http://jsfiddle.net/nn4x8/4/

If you want to send server request on every sort change, same handler for 'sortupdate' event. E.g.:

```
$("#sortable_nav_items").bind('sortupdate', function() {
    var order = $(this).sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"});
    $.post(
        "content.cfc",
        {method:"sortOrder",data:order}
    );
});
```

Comment: i have content.cfc in admin/services/content.cfc... when i passed it like this it is giving me internal server error.

Comment: can you tell me after sorting it how can i redirect to other page ?

Comment: `$("button").click(function(){
   var order = $("#sortable_nav_items").sortable("toArray",{attribute:"pageid"});
   $.post(
    "/org/regionscms/remote/proxy.cfc",
    {method:"sortOrder",data:order}
   );
   .done(function (order, textStatus){
    window.location.href = '/pages/list.cfm';
   })
  });`
i have tried this... .done method

Comment: What specifically is not working in this code? Check if request is actually being sent to server and contains all data you need. Check if the server script works as desired and returns appropriate data. Check if the done callback is being ever called. etc. I believe that kind of research is what you should be doing yourself. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $.post( "content.cfc", { data: $(this).sortable('toArray') } ).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Alternate of POST in jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "content.cfc",
dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(){
sortOrder()
},
  data: {'data':$(this).sortable('toArray')},
  success: function(result){
alert(result)
},

});
```

Comment: where you are calling method ?

Comment: what is the use of SortOrder method I didn't find your code ?

Comment: this method has the update query to update the ordering.